# How to scroll selected item to visible in NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

In my app, when NSOpenPanel opens, it shows a preselected NSURL item, the file though selected, is not visible. I have to scroll down to see the selected file. Is there a method like:

```
scrollRowToVisible:
```

on NSOpenPanel.

This is my code:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"txt", nil];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
[openPanel setDirectoryURL:[self getFileURL]];

// Show the open panel and process the results.
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSURL*  selectedFileUrl = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
        //saving code here
}
```

Comment: This works ok in OS X 10.10. In 10.11 the file isn't always visible. I think Apple changed things and didn't test everything (as usual).